# Php function or class that receive time and duration and return crontab string

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, cron

I need to get crontab string if I know only next time, when job  will run and duration. For example, I know that jobs starts at 17hours, and duration is 86400 seconds (1 day) - job starts at 17 every day. I need universal function, that returns crontab time string for diferent start times and durations. For my example "0 17 * * *". Anybody helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a pretty comprehensive answer to the question:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/